# Responsive table with fixed two left columns and header

Tags: html, html-table, responsive

I have read some articles about this problem but wasn't able to solve it. Most of example shows table where header consist of one row, and in same time rows are single row, like calendar. My table has double-row header and row start with rowspan, so I couldn't make it works. I need fixed first two columns (or only left column) and fixed header, so rest of columns are scrollable to right if screen is narrowed. Here is table

```
    <table class="responsive">
    <tbody>             
    <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">CITY</th>
    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">YP</th>
    <th colspan="3" scope="col">MORNING</th>
    <th colspan="3" scope="col">MORNING</th>
    <th colspan="3" scope="col">NIGHT</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Temp</td>
    <td>Sun</td>
    <td>Wind</td>
    <td>Temp</td>
    <td>Sun</td>
    <td>Wind</td>
    <td>Temp</td>
    <td>Sun</td>
    <td>Wind</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Name of city 1</th>
    <td>I</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>96</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>II</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>96</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>98</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    </tr>
    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Name of city 2</th>
    <td>I</td>
    <td>77</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>88</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>II</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>82</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>87</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

I tried with Zurb Studio - Crafty Responsive Tables but complex nature of my table doesn't match demo example.

[image]

Comment: No one? Not a simple clue, link? Unbelievable.

Comment: Can you make a working fiddle. I think this should be responsive already.

Answer (score 0):

After some long websites research, I think that plug-in called **RowsGroup** should help. Until now I didn't realize right procedure to solve my own table but this is nice start. I had hope that someone would help me but it seems that in some case everything is up to question author. :/